# is there anything i can add to my code to avoid this key error

Tags: variables, keyerror

```
col_dict = {'Life_expectancy':1,'Adult_mortality':2,'Infant_deaths':3,'Alcohol':4,'Percentage_expenditure':5,'HepatitisB':6,'Measles':7,'BMI':8,'Under_five_deaths':9,'Polio':10,'Total_expenditure':11,'Diphtheria':12,'HIV/AIDS':13,'GDP':14,'Population':15,'Thinness_1-19_years':16,'Thinness_5-9_years':17,'Income_composition_of_resources':18,'Schooling':19}

# Detect outliers in each variable using box plots.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,30))

for variable,i in col_dict.items():
                     plt.subplot(5,4,i)
                     plt.boxplot(life_expectancy[variable])
                     plt.title(variable)
                     plt.grid(True)
    
plt.show()
```

why am i getting key error in this line plt.boxplot(life_expectancy[variable])